# What are the functions in Blender that will help me render this scene on limited hardware? My pc: win 10, i7, 4G graphics, 16G Ram

Tags: modeling, mesh, texturing

[image]

The houses are already built in quite detail, what tips can you give me to lower the poly count or to keep my pc from freezing? Display the houses in "textured wrapped square boxes"? Will it work to duplicate a few houses and see how my pc handle it?

[image: demo picture]

I want to do a fly over and pan around the town houses while keeping the same altitude. Then I want to lower the altitude half the distance. Can I use transparent images for the trees?

What pc specs are needed?

Comment: Depends on level of detail and what exactly you want to do.  There are lots of tricks but for right now this is an extremely broad question with little detail.  It's probably a good candidate to chop up into multiple questions once you have some idea of how you're going about it and where any slowdowns are coming from

Comment: The houses are already built in quite detail, what tips can you give me to lower the poly count or to keep my pc from freezing? Display the houses in "textured wrapped square boxes"?  Will it work to duplicate a few houses and see how my pc handle it?

Comment: From this distance primitive shapes should work with good textures.  Animation like a zoom will complicate things.  That's what I mean, if you can [edit] your question to give some more idea of what you want to do it will be queued for review to be reopened and perhaps someone can give you a full answer.

Comment: Wording it like that will help to conform to our rules as well.  "What are the functions *in Blender* that will help me render this scene on limited hardware?" or some such

Comment: I want to do a fly over and pan around the town houses while keeping the same altitude.  Then I want to lower the altitude half the distance.  Can I use transparent images for the trees?